# Spring XD -- xd-singlenode start failure

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-boot, spring-xd

I have set the environment variable `spring.profiles.active` to `"qa"` which is the profile in `application.yml` file which i want to activate.

But after setting this environment variable, and starting Sprind XD in xd-singlenode, it throws me the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.job.DistributedJobService#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/batch/batch.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobExecutionDao' while setting constructor argument; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobExecutionDao' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring-xd/batch/batch.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not inspect meta data for database type.  You have to supply it explicitly.
```

What might be the exception ??
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's true. Since you don't use `hsqldbServer` profile you have to define the `dataSource` bean one your own. See `hsql-datasource.xml`.

Or just make both those profiles as `active`.